# Why is x=x++ undefined?

Tags: c, language-design

It's undefined because the it modifies `x` twice between sequence points. The standard says it's undefined, therefore it's undefined.
That much I know.

#### But why?

My understanding is that forbidding this allows compilers to optimize better. This could have made sense when C was invented, but now seems like a weak argument.
If we were to reinvent C today, would we do it this way, or can it be done better?
Or maybe there's a deeper problem, that makes it hard to define consistent rules for such expressions, so it's best to forbid them?

So suppose we were to reinvent C today. I'd like to suggest simple rules for expressions such as `x=x++`, which seem to me to work better than the existing rules.
I'd like to get your opinion on the suggested rules compared to the existing ones, or other suggestions.

#### Suggested Rules:

1. Between sequence points, order of evaluation is unspecified.
2. Side effects take place immediately.

There's no undefined behavior involved. Expressions evaluate to this value or that, but surely won't format your hard disk (strangely, I've never seen an implementation where `x=x++` formats the hard disk).

#### Example Expressions

1. `x=x++` - Well defined, doesn't change `x`.
   First, `x` is incremented (immediately when `x++` is evaluated), then it's old value is stored in `x`.
2. `x++ + ++x` - Increments `x` twice, evaluates to `2*x+2`.
   Though either side may be evaluated first, the result is either `x + (x+2)` (left side first) or `(x+1) + (x+1)` (right side first).
3. `x = x + (x=3)` - Unspecified, `x` set to either `x+3` or `6`.
   If the right side is evaluated first, it's `x+3`. It's also possible that `x=3` is evaluated first, so it's `3+3`. In either case, the `x=3` assignment happens immediately when `x=3` is evaluated, so the value stored is overwritten by the other assignment.
4. `x+=(x=3)` - Well defined, sets `x` to 6.
   You could argue that this is just shorthand for the expression above.
   But I'd say that `+=` must be executed after `x=3`, and not in two parts (read `x`, evaluate `x=3`, add and store new value).

#### What's the Advantage?

Some comments raised this good point.
I certainly don't think expressions such as `x=x++` should be used in any normal code.
Actually, I'm much more strict than that - I think the only good usage for `x++` in as `x++;` alone.

However, I think the language rules must be as simple as possible. Otherwise programmers just don't understand them. the rule forbidding changing a variable twice between sequence points is certainly a rule most programmers don't understand.

A very basic rule is this:
If A is valid, and B is valid, and they're combined in a valid way, the result is valid.
`x` is a valid L-value, `x++` is a valid expression, and `=` is a valid way to combine an L-value and an expression, so how come `x=x++` isn't legal?
The C standard makes an exception here, and this exception complicates the rules. You can search [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) and see how much this exception confuses people.
So I say - get rid of this confusion.

=== Summary of Answers ===

1. Why do that?
   I tried to explain in the section above - I want C rules to be simple.
2. Potential for optimization:
   This does take some freedom from the compiler, but I didn't see anything that convinced me that it might be significant.
   Most optimizations can still be done. For example, `a=3;b=5;` can be reordered, even though the standard specifies the order. Expressions such as `a=b[i++]` can still be optimized similarly.
3. You can't change the existing standard.
   I admit, I can't. I never thought I can actually go ahead and change standards and compilers. I only wanted to think if things could have been done differently.

Comment: You point 2. makes even the simplest optimizations impossible, I wouldn't want to trade that in just so I can `x=x++`. Maybe you could make a point why these new rules would be better than what currently almost every C-like language does.

Comment: @honk, I don't see why it makes optimizations impossible. For example, `x=x++`, which doesn't change `x`, can be optimized to nothing.

Comment: Why is this important to you? *Should* it be defined, and if so, why? There's not much point in assigning `x` to itself, and if you want to increment `x` you can just say `x++;` -- no need for the assignment. I'd say it *should not* be defined just because it'd be hard to remember what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Case in point: Java (and I believe C# as well) *do* have defined behaviour for those statements. It's still a bad idea to use them, because they are still confusing to humans.

Comment: @Caleb, I think the current rules are very unclear and confusing. Half the C questions in stackoverflow.com are about this. I think my suggestions make it much easier to predict an expression's result.

Comment: In my mind, this is a good question ("Some men see things as they are and ask why, I dream things that never were and ask why not"). It's (in my opinion) a question purely on language design, using C syntax as an example, not a question on C syntax. I, personally, think that the reason we don't have defined behaviour for expressions such as x++ + ++x or x=x++ is simply because there is a possibility of them being misread.

Comment: @ugoren: Why do you need to predict the result. Nobody in their right mind would write code like that (as has been mentioned several times) even if you did write code like this it would be rejected at the first code review. So there is no need to define the behavior and give the optimizer the best chance at optimizing it. In every example you propose I would shoot somebody if they added that to the code base.

Comment: Interesting question. Notice that in C#, x+=(x=3) results in 3 not 6 (assuming x was 0 before the statement).

Comment: @EmmadKareem, is this guaranteed behavior in C#? Or is it unspecified, as in my `x=x+(x=3)` example?

Comment: I would find a more interesting question to be why isn't an error to write this? Surely a compiler could detect it's undefined behavour and therefore can't possibly be what the user actually wanted, so why isn't in an error? I understand some instances of undefined bahavour are hard to detect but this isn;t

Comment: @ugoren, in C#,  int x=0; x = x + (x = 3); results in x holding 3 - No errors or warning in either cases.

Comment: @JohnB As much as undefined behavior is undesireable in production code, it generally is not illegal according to the language spec. Dereferencing an unitialized variable as a pointer (something like `int paddr; char *p = *paddr;`) often is also undefined behavior.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, I'm not arguing about undefined behavior in general. I'm just trying to remove the rule that makes `x=x++` undefined.

Comment: There are several questions and I'm confused about which ones you are really interested. Why the current state? What better state could be reasonably achieved as an evolution of C? What state would be desirable for C if one wasn't constrained? What state would be desirable for a "C like" language?  If it is one of later two, I would tend to vote to close your question as "non constructive", i.e. far too open to get a definitive answer.

Comment: "*the rule forbidding changing a variable twice between sequence points is certainly a rule most programmers don't understand.*" -- Do you have any evidence for this? Most questions I've seen were asked because the programmers didn't **know** about the rule. Is there any evidence that most of them still didn't **understand** it after it was explained?

Comment: @Secure, Your distinction is probably correct, but I don't think it matters much - this rule is a big source of misunderstanding. I do think the rule is hard to explain - the kind of thing a person understands when you explain, possibly remembers, and fails to connect with real code when it's relevant.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!"  "Well, *don't do that!*"

Answer (score 25):

Maybe you should first answer the question why it should be defined? Is there any advantage in programming style, readability, maintainability or performance by allowing such expressions with additional side effects? Is

```
y = x++ + ++x;
```

more readable than

```
y = 2*x + 2;
x += 2;
```

Given that such a change is extremely fundamental and breaking to the existing code base.

Comment: I added a "why" section to my question. I surely don't suggest using these expressions, but I'm interested in having simple rules to tell the meaning of an expression.

Comment: Also, this change doesn't break existing code, unless it invoked undefined behavior. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, a more philosophical answer: It's currently undefined. If no programmer uses it, then there is no need for you to understand such expressions, because there shouldn't be any code. If there is a need for you to understand them, then obviously there must be a lot of code out there that relies on undefined behaviour. ;)

Comment: @ugoren - Don't underestimate the power of change for breaking code. The most obvious are: (1) code that relies on undefined behaviour in a specific environment, and (2) performances issues if code is recompiled with a "new defined C" compiler.

Comment: @mouviciel, Such code can break on compiler change without a change in language definitions. I first met `x=x++` when debugging a problem after switching from GCC 2.x to 4.x.

Comment: It is, by definition, not breaking any existing codebase to define the behaviours. If they contained UB, they were, by definition, already broken.

Comment: @ugoren : Your "why" section still doesn't answer the practical question: *why* would you want this freakish expression in your code? If you can't come up with a convincing answer to that, then the whole discussion is moot.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak, I don't want this in my code. I also don't want `y=x++` and `if(x++<3)` and `while(*p++=*q++);`, which are all legal. I think the only good usage for `x++` is `x++;`. But I think the rules for what's legal and what isn't should be as clear and simple as possible.

Comment: @ugoren - the rule *is* clear and simple: `y=x++` is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say: `x=x++` is not allowed.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak, "`x=x++` is not allowed" certainly isn't the rule. It's just one case of a rule most C programmers don't understand.

Comment: @Mike if it’s so clear and simple, why don’t compilers catch violations?

Answer (score 23):

The argument that making this undefined behavior allows better optimization is *not* weak today. In fact, it's much *stronger* today than it was when C was new.

When C was new, machines that could take advantage of this for better optimization were mostly theoretical models. People had talked about the possibility of building CPUs where the compiler would instruct the CPU about what instructions could/should be executed in parallel with other instructions. They pointed to the fact that allowing this to have undefined behavior meant that on such a CPU, if it ever really existed, you could schedule the "increment" part of the instruction to execute in parallel with the rest of the instruction stream. While they were right about the theory, at the time there was little in the way of hardware that could really take advantage of this possibility.

That's not just theoretical anymore. Now there is hardware in production, and in wide use, (e.g., Itanium, VLIW DSPs) that can *really* take advantage of this. They really *do* allow the compiler to generate an instruction stream that specifies that instructions X, Y and Z can all be executed in parallel. This is no longer a theoretical model -- it's real hardware in real use doing real work.

IMO, making this defined behavior is close to the *worst* possible "solution" to the problem. You clearly should not use expressions like this. For the vast majority of code, the ideal behavior would be for the compiler to simply reject such expressions entirely. At the time, C compilers didn't do the flow analysis necessary to detect that dependably. Even at the time of the original C standard, it still wasn't at all common.

I'm not sure it would be acceptable to the community today either -- while many compilers can do that kind of flow analysis, they typically only do it when you request optimization. I doubt most programmers would like the idea of slowing down "debug" builds just for the sake of being able to reject code they (being sane) would never write in the first place.

What C has done is a semi-reasonable second-best choice: tell people not to do that, allowing (but not requiring) the compiler to reject the code. This avoids (still further) slowing compilation for people who'd never use it, but still allows somebody to write a compiler that will reject such code if they want to (and/or have flags that will reject it that people can choose to use or not as they see fit).

At least IMO, making this defined behavior would be (at least close to) the *worst* possible decision to make. On VLIW-style hardware, you choices would be to generate slower code for the reasonable uses of the increment operators, just for the sake of crappy code that abuses them, or else always require extensive flow analysis to prove that you aren't dealing with crappy code, so you can produce the slow (serialized) code only when truly necessary.

Bottom line: if you want to cure this problem, you should be thinking in the opposite direction. Instead of defining what such code does, you should define the language so such expressions simply aren't allowed at all (and live with the fact that most programmers will probably opt for faster compilation over enforcing that requirement).

Comment: IMO, there is little reason to believe that in most cases, the slower instructions are really that much slower than the fast instructions and that these will always have an impact on program performance. I would class this one under premature optimization.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - if nobody's ever supposed to write such code, why care about optimizing it?

Comment: @ugoren: writing code like `a=b[i++];` (for one example) is fine, and optimizing it is a good thing. I don't, however, see the point of hurting reasonable code like that just so something like `++i++` has a defined meaning.

Comment: With `a=b[i++]`, the compiler is free to optimize if `a` and `i` are distinct. If aliasing is possible (maybe in `*p=b[i++]`, where `p` might be `&i`), the compiler's room for optimization is limited anyway. I don't think optimizing `*p=b[i++]` is more important than `*p=b[i];i++;` (where order is dictated by the standard).

Comment: @ugoren The problem is one of diagnosis. The only purpose of not outright disallowing expressions such as `++i++` is precisely that it’s in general hard to distinguish them from valid expressions with side-effects (such as `a=b[i++]`). It may seem simple enough for us, bu if I remember the *Dragon Book* correctly then it’s actually an NP-hard problem. *That’s* why this behaviour is UB, rather than forbidden.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, But I'm suggesting to make it allowed. With my suggestion, there's nothing to detect - the compiler will handle `a=b++` and `a=a++` the same way. Detecting whether pointers may alias is indeed a hard problem, but the compilers have to face it anyway.

Comment: @ugoren The whole point is that handling these two scenarios identically throws away valuable optimisations. This is simply not a viable choice. Either you forbid them (requires detection), or you treat them differently, optimising one via reordering while keeping the other one ordered (requires detection), or you treat them identically and optimise (implies UB for some cases).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I keep hearing about optimizations, but can't see anything really convincing. The compiler can do lots of useful reordering even if the language mandates an order (e.g. `a=3;b=5;` can be flipped). Doing a few more reorderings within complicated expressions doesn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: @ugren: On one hand, you're right that a single instance of `i++` being serialize won't kill things. OTOH, these operations often happen a *lot*. Another point to keep in mind is that vendors often care as much about benchmark results as real code. Just for example, if Intel's SPEC results went down 5%, they would probably lose a lot *more* than 5% in sales from it.

Comment: I don't believe that performance is a valid argument. I struggle to believe that the case is common enough, considering the very slim difference and very fast execution in both cases, for a small performance drop to be noticable- not to mention that on *many* processors and architectures, defining it is effectively free.

Comment: @DeadMG: well, at least for you the answer seems obvious: define it in `wide`, and see how it works out (and no, I'm not being sarcastic, I'm quite serious). I'd really like to see the result in a language that's otherwise similar enough to compare the two meaningfully.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I did indeed. However, of course, first it would have to be both finished and implemented to a comparable level :P

Comment: "[T]he ideal behavior would be for the compiler to simply reject such expressions entirely. At the time, C compilers didn't do the flow analysis necessary to detect that dependably" -- and yet, Pascal (an older language than C) managed to avoid the problem entirely, by simply not providing any constructs that allowed programmers to write expressions with multiple modifications.

Comment: I think the problem isn't really expresions like `i = i++`, which as pointed out can be detected and optimised carefully if required -- the real issue is expressions like `*a = (*b)++`, where it isn't possible in the general case to know that `a` and `b` aren't pointers to the same location.  Avoiding undefined behaviour in this example means avoiding all forms of memory update reordering, which would put a serious dent in the performance of a C like language (and is one of the main reasons why Fortran still dominates many numerical benchmarks, as this kind of problem cannot arise there).

Comment: As an example of a potential optimisation that can be carried out *only* because this is undefined behaviour consider the code `(*a) = (*b)++; return *b;`. If the behaviour of this is defined such that `*a` is updated after `*b` then the compiler must load the value of `*b` back into a register after updating `*a` to ensure that `*a` didn't modify it (assuming `a` and `b` have the same type, activating C's strict aliasing rules). If the behaviour of multiple updates of the same location is undefined, however, the compiler is free to simply keep hold of the value of `*b` and return it directly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wonder if we could defeat an evil AI by presenting an NP-hard problem to it? "*Computer, this is a Class A computing directive...*"

Comment: @nocomprende That’s an old trope in science fiction, and it usually fails because the AI has a protection circuit against it. At its simplest, they can use a timeout to abort computations. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Eric Lippert, a principal designer on the C# compiler team, posted on his blog [an article](https://ericlippert.com/2012/06/18/implementation-defined-behaviour/) about a number of considerations that go into choosing to make a feature undefined at the language spec level.  Obviously C# is a differently language, with different factors going into its language design, but the points he makes are relevant nonetheless.

In particular, he points out the issue of having existing compilers for a language that have existing implementations and also have representatives on a committee.  I'm not sure if that's the case here, but tends to be relevant to most C and C++ related spec discussions.

Also of note is, as you said, the performance potential for compiler optimization.  While it's true that the performance of CPUs these days are many orders of magnitude greater than they were when C was young, a large amount of C programming done these days are done specifically because of the potential performance gain, and the potential for (hypothetical future) CPU instruction optimizations and multicore processing optimizations would be silly to preclude because of an overly-restrictive set of rules for handling side effects and sequence points.

Comment: From the article you link to, it seems like C# isn't far from what I suggest. Ordering of side effects is defined "when observed from the thread that causes the side effects". I didn't mention multi-threading, but in general C doesn't guarantee much for an observer in another thread.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's take a look at the [definition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) of undefined behavior:

> #### 3.4.3
>
> 1 **undeﬁned behavior**
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
> for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
> 2 NOTE Possible undeﬁned behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable
> results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
> environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or
> execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).
> 3 EXAMPLE An example of undeﬁned behavior is the behavior on integer overﬂow

So in other words, "undefined behavior" simply means that the compiler is free to handle the situation any way it wants to, and any such action is considered "correct".

The root of the issue under discussion is the following clause:

> #### 6.5 Expressions
>
> ...
> 3 The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.
> <sup>74)</sup>
> Except as speciﬁed
> later (for the function-call `()`, `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and comma operators), **the order of evaluation
> of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspeciﬁed**.

Emphasis added.

Given an expression like

```
x = a++ * --b / (c + ++d);
```

the subexpressions `a++`, `--b`, `c`, and `++d` may be evaluated **in any order**.  Furthermore, the side effects of `a++`, `--b`, and `++d` may be applied at any point before the next sequence point (IOW, even if `a++` is evaluated before `--b`, it's not guaranteed that `a` will be *updated*  before `--b` is evaluated).  Like others have said, the rationale for this behavior is to give the implementation the freedom to reorder operations in an optimal manner.

Because of this, however, expressions like

```
x = x++
y = i++ * i++
a[i] = i++
*p++ = -*p    // this one bit me just yesterday
```

etc., will yield *different results for different implementations* (or for the same implementation with different optimization settings, or based on the surrounding code, etc.).

The behavior is left *undefined* so that the compiler is under no obligation to "do the right thing", whatever that may be.  The cases above are easy enough to catch, but there a non-trivial number of cases that would be difficult to impossible to catch at compile time.

Obviously, you *can* design a language such that order of evaluation and the order in which side effects are applied are strictly defined, and both Java and C# do so, largely to avoid the issues that the C and C++ definitions lead to.

So, why hasn't this change been made to C after 3 standard revisions?  First of all, there's 40 years' worth of legacy C code out there, and it's not guaranteed that such a change won't break that code.  It puts a bit of a burden on compiler writers, as such a change would immediately make all existing compilers non-conforming; everybody'd have to make significant rewrites.  And even on fast, modern CPUs, it's still possible to realize real performance gains by tweaking order of evaluation.

Comment: Very good explanation of the issue. I disagree about breaking legacy applications - the way undefined/unspecified behavior is implemented sometimes changes between compiler version, without any change in the standard. I don't suggest to change any defined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

First you have to understand that it's not just x=x++ that is undefined. Nobody cares about x=x++, since no matter what you would define it to there's no point to it. What's undefined is more like "a=b++ where a and b happen to be the same" - i.e.

```
void f(int *a, int *b) {
    *a = (*b)++;
}
int i;
f(&i, &i);
```

There several different ways the function might be implemented, depending on what is most efficient for the processor architecture (and for the surrounding statements, in case this is a more complex function than the example). For example, two obvious ones:

```
load r1 = *b
copy r2 = r1
increment r1
store *b = r1
store *a = r2
```

or

```
load r1 = *b
store *a = r1
increment r1
store *b = r1
```

Note that the first one listed above, the one that uses more instructions and more registers, is the one that you would require to be used in all cases where a and b cannot be proven to be different.

Comment: You indeed show a case where my suggestion results in more machine operations, but it looks insignificant to me. And the compiler still has some freedom - the only real requirement I add is to store `b` before `a`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Legacy

The assumption that C could be reinvented today cannot hold. There are so many lines of C codes that have been produced and are daily used, that changing the rules of the game in the middle of the play is just wrong.

Of course you can invent a new language, say *C+=*, with your rules. But that will not be C.

Comment: I don't really think we can reinvent C today. This doesn't mean we can't discuss these issues. However, what I suggest isn't really reinventing. Converting undefined behavior to defined or unspecified can be done when updating a standard, and the language would still be C.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring that something is defined won't change the existing compilers to respect your definition. That is especially true in the case of an assumption which may have been relied on explicitly or implicitly in a lot of places.

The major issue for the assumption isn't with `x = x++;` (compilers can easily check for it and should warn), it is with `*p1 = (*p2)++` and equivalent (`p1[i] = p2[j]++;` when p1 and p2 are parameters to a function) where the compiler can't know easily if `p1 == p2` (in C99 `restrict` has been added to spread out the possibility of assuming p1 != p2 between sequence points, so it was deemed that the optimization possibilities were important).

Comment: I don't see how my suggestion changes anything in regard to `p1[i]=p2[j]++`. If the compiler can assume no aliasing, there's no issue. If it can't, it must go by the book - increment `p2[j]` first, store `p1[i]` later. Except for the optimization opportunities lost, which don't seem significant, I see no issue.

Comment: The second paragraph wasn't independent from the first, but an example of the kind of places where the assumption can creep in and will be difficult to track.

Comment: The first paragraph states something quite obvious - compilers will have to be changed to comply to a new standard. I don't really think I have a chance to standardize this and make the compiler writers follow. I just think it's worth discussing.

Comment: The problem isn't that one need to change the compilers about any change in the language needs it, it is that the changes are pervasive and at place hard to find. The most practical approach would probably be changing the intermediate format on which the optimizer works, i.e. pretending that `x = x++;` hasn't been written but `t = x; x++; x = t;` or `x=x; x++;` or whatever you want as semantic (but what about diagnostics?). For a new language, just drop out side effects.

Comment: I don't know too too much about compiler structure. If I really wanted to change all compilers, I would care more. But maybe treating `x++` as a sequence point, as if it was a function call `inc_and_return_old(&x)` would do the trick.

Comment: @ugoren: The optimization opportunities are _very_ significant. We are talking about kind of statement that happen to be used in tight loops with millions and billions of iterations.

Answer (score -2):

In some cases, this kind of code *was* defined in the new C++11 Standard.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: I think `x = ++x` is now well-defined (but not `x = x++`)